# How to solve ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

```
var spinner = element(by.css('.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok.green:not(.ng-hide)'));
expect(spinner.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
spinner.click();
```

when I execute this always receiving an error as

```
ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
```

I want to select this element

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green" data-ng-show="Choice.IsCorrect"/>
```

and not to select other element as

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green ng-hide" data-ng-show="Choice.IsCorrect"/>
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML representation of the spinner? (or share the link to reproduce it) Thanks.

Comment: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green" data-ng-show="Choice.IsCorrect"/> I want to select this element and not to select other element as<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green ng-hide" data-ng-show="Choice.IsCorrect"/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of doing it as below

```
var popUp = ($('[data-ng-show="Choice.IsCorrect"].glyphicon.glyphicon-ok.green:not(.ng-hide)'));
popUp.click();
```

so this will always return the visible element and can click on it.

Thank you everyone for looking into it.